# Running script on page load

Tags: javascript

I am using the following code to run a calculation as the user type in a number.

```
   <form action="index.php" method="post" autocomplete="off" data-abide>
   <input type="text" id="rate" name="rate">
   <input type="text" name="supplier_cost" class="value-right" pattern="\d*" value="<?php echo $supplier_cost; ?>" id="decimal" required>
   <input type="text" name="sterling" id="sterling" class="value-right" disabled>
   <button type="submit" class="button tiny ebc-theme" name="save"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> SAVE</button>
   </form>

$(document).ready(function(){

        var supplier_id = $('#supplier').val().split(",");
        var period = "<?php echo $period; ?>";
        $.ajax({
            url: "fetch_rate.php",
            method: "POST",
            data:{supplierID:supplier_id[1], periodID:period},
            dataType:"text",
            success:function(data)
            {
                $('#rate').val(data);
            }
        });

});

   $(document).ready(SterlingCalc); 
   document.getElementById('decimal').addEventListener("keyup", SterlingCalc);

   var rate = document.getElementById('rate');
   var sup_cost = document.getElementById('decimal');

   function SterlingCalc(){

      document.getElementById('sterling').value = (sup_cost.value / rate.value).toFixed(2) || 0;

   }
```

How do I add code so that the calulation runs on the page load if both the "rate" and "decimal" fields are already loaded (for example, values are populated by database)?

Thanks,

John

Comment: Invoke`SterlingCalc()`

Comment: that function gets invoked by jquery. no need to invoke it by hand

Comment: NaN (not a number) is caused by a division with something that is not a number or is indeterminate like 0/0. What is your php code?

Comment: The issue may because I am getting the rate using an Ajax query. I didn't include this earlier as I thought it would over complicate things and that the value was displaying in the input field.

Comment: `toFixed(2) || 0` makes no sense, because toFixed(2) returns always a string and is always true. So `|| 0` is never executed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    SterlingCalc();
    document.getElementById('decimal').addEventListener("keyup", function(){SterlingCalc()});
});

function SterlingCalc(){
    var rate = document.getElementById('rate');
    var sup_cost = document.getElementById('decimal');
    document.getElementById('sterling').value = (sup_cost.value / rate.value).toFixed(2) || 0;
}
```

Reasoning:
With `$(document).ready(function(){ XXX })` you basically execute the code (XXX) when the document is loaded. Therefore, if the page loads the keybinding is put on 'decimal'.

Comment: yes this one is more correct. my answer leads to assignig the event listener on key press.

Comment: I tried this and the sterling input field shows "Infinity".

Comment: what do you mean can you explain? or share an screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

you are tryng to mix some of jquery with standard js that it's not a best practice, with jquery you can do something like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

     let sterlingFunc = function (){

     let rate = $('#rate');
     let sup_cost = $('#decimal');
     let value = (sup_cost.value / rate.value).toFixed(2) || 0;
     $('#sterling').val(value);
     // maybe return value
     }

     $("#decimal").on("keyup", sterlingFunc());

     // to run when page is loaded 
     sterlingFunc();  

    });
```

Comment: this code is not doing the same thing. your code does not invoke `sterlingFunc` on document ready. it just defines it. Am I right?

Comment: yes, but he added an event listener so he wants to invoke the function on keyup not on page load, the ready function is needed to prevent from loading something before inizialization

Comment: How to you know he does not want to run it on page load as well? >> How do I add code so that the calulation runs on the page load if both the "rate" and "decimal" fields are already loaded

Comment: Mishel is right. I want to be able to run it on page load or keyup.

Comment: Sorry, not good on jQuery. How do I return the value so it appears in the sterling field?

Comment: Just tried it and that code does not work on either page load or keyup. Getting no errors, just doesn't work.

Comment: is sterling an input field?

Comment: Yes, it's an input field.

Comment: just edited my answer, try now and be sure to include jquery in your html file

Comment: jQuery is included. I now get NaN in the sterling field on either page load or keyup.